# return new columns by subtracting two columns in a pandas list

Tags: python, pandas, list

It seems so basic, but I can't work out how to achieve the following...

Consider the scenario where I have the following data:

```py
all_columns = ['A','B','C','D']
first_columns = ['A','B']
second_columns = ['C','D']
new_columns = ['E','F']
values = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data = values, columns = all_columns)
df
    A   B   C   D
0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8
2   9  10  11  12
3  13  14  15  16
```

How can I using this data subsequently subtract let's say column C - column A, then column D - column B and return two new columns E and F respectively to my df Pandas dataframe? I have multiple columns so writing the formula one by one is not an option.

I imagine it should be something like that, but python thinks that I am trying to subtract list names rather than the values in the actual lists...

```py
df[new_columns] = df[second_columns] - df[first_columns]
```

Expected output:

```py
    A   B   C   D   E   F 
0   1   2   3   4   2   2
1   5   6   7   8   2   2
2   9  10  11  12   2   2
3  13  14  15  16   2   2
```

Comment: Change `df[first_columns]` by `df[first_columns].values` it should work

Comment: Just avoid index matching by subtracting from an array `df[['E', 'F']] = df[['C', 'D']] - df[['A', 'B']].values`

Comment: Thank you @Ben.T your provided answer worked like a charm! :)

Comment: @Klaudijus good :) also please consider accepting one of the below [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['E'] = df['C'] - df['A']
df['F'] = df['D'] - df['B']
```

Or, alternatively (similar to @rafaelc's comment):

```
new_cols = ['E', 'F']
second_cols = ['C', 'D']
first_cols = ['A', 'B']

df[new_cols] = df[second_cols] - df[first_cols].values
```

Answer (score 1):

As @rafaelc and @Ben.T mentioned .. below would be the good fit to go.

I'm Just placing this is in the answer section for the posterity use...

```
>>> df
    A   B   C   D
0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8
2   9  10  11  12
3  13  14  15  16
```

### Result:

```
>>> df[['E', 'F']] = df[['C', 'D']] - df[['A', 'B']].values
>>> df
    A   B   C   D  E  F
0   1   2   3   4  2  2
1   5   6   7   8  2  2
2   9  10  11  12  2  2
3  13  14  15  16  2  2
```

Comment: Jaap, adding .values next to the column list worked like a charm - cheers!